# How to interpolate tabulated data in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I'm looking at the conversion of wind speed to power generation for a wind turbine. I have a text file containing two columns-wind speed in the first, associated power in the second. The resolution is 1ms-1 for 0 to 25ms-1. I plan to import this to a script in Python.

Anyone know how to interpolate the data using Python, in order to obtain the power for an arbitrary wind speed, say 7.6ms-1 or something like that?

Comment: How does data look like?

Comment: Edit the post with samples of the data, what your expected result is and what have you already tried, it's hard to figure out a solution without a clear understanding of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `numpy.interp` function: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html

The code would look something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("yourfile.csv")
wanted_wind_speed = 7.6
interpolated_power = np.interp(wanted_wind_speed, data['wind'], data['power'])
```